# How to add box layer using levelplot in R?

Tags: r, levelplot

I would like to add some boxes with special extent to my plot.

Example

```
     gh <- raster()
     gh[] <- 1:ncell(gh)
     SP <- spsample(Spatial(bbox=bbox(gh)), 10, type="random")
```

Then plot them

```
  levelplot(gh, col.regions = rev(terrain.colors(255)), cuts=254, margin=FALSE) +
  layer(sp.points(SP, col = "red"))
```

this plots a map with several crosses in it but I need to plot a box with spacial extent:

```
     extent(gh) = extent(c(xmn=-180,xmx=180,ymn=-90,ymx=90))
      e6 <- extent( 2  , 8 , 45   , 51  )
```

[image]

I wan to add `e6` to the plot and put the number`2` inside the box.Any hint please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the `Extent` object into a `SpatialPolygons`, and extract its centroid with `coordinates`:

```
library("raster")
library("sp")
library("rasterVis")

gh <- raster()
gh[] <- 1:ncell(gh)
SP <- spsample(Spatial(bbox=bbox(gh)), 10, type="random")

e6 <- extent( 2, 8, 45, 51)
e6pol <- as(e6, 'SpatialPolygons')
centroid <- coordinates(e6pol)

levelplot(gh, col.regions = rev(terrain.colors(255)), cuts=254, margin=FALSE) +
    layer({sp.points(SP, col = "red")
           sp.polygons(e6pol)
           panel.text(centroid[,1], centroid[,2], '2')
           })
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. How you control the zise of the number 2 inside the box

Comment: Use `cex` inside `panel.text`. You will find the details in `?panel.text`.